# HTTP 404 file not found error even the file exist in the webserver IIS6.0

Tags: iis-6

I am having files in the server to be available for downloads. I am using IIS6.0. When I try to download the pdf file it say Http 404 file not found error. But I am having the file in the server. While googling I found we need to enable the mime type. can any one explain me what is it and get rid of this problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is easy enough to sort out

To enable globally on the all site hosted by this IIS instance

```
Open IIS Manager
Right Click the server name
Select properties
Click the MIME Types button
Click New
Extension is .pdf
MIME type is application/pdf
```

To add it only to a single site on the IIS instance

```
Open IIS Manager
Right Click the sites name
Select Properties
Choose the 'HTTP Headers' tab
Click the MIME Types button
Click New
Extension is .pdf
MIME type is application/pdf
```

Answer (score 1):

Open Internet Information Service(IIS) Manager

Right click on your website

Select HTTP Header tab

You will find button to add MIME Types

This [link](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/cd72c0dc-c5b8-42e4-96c2-b3c656f99ead.mspx?mfr=true) might be helpful to you.

Comment: ok Thank you I added the MIME Type for pdf extension but still i am receiving File not found error Http 404

Comment: did you specified MIME type as "application/pdf" while adding ?\

Answer (score 0):

You will find help in the Microsoft Knowledge Base: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/326965